# Removing element using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using jquery token input in my program and according to a select list change i need to pass extra parameter to the search function. I am able to do it  by below code.

```
$("#service").on('change', '.act_type', function () {  
qq = $(this).val();
var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
$("#token-input-code-" + id[1]).detach();
$("#code-"+id[1]).tokenInput("../Preapproval/Searchactivitycode?queryParam=q" + "&type=" + qq,{
theme: 'facebook',
preventDuplicates: true,
searchingText: 'Searching...',
tokenLimit: 1,
hintText: 'Activity code',
 });
```

the rows are creating dynamically. I will detach the current textbox having the token input when a change in select list is done. Otherwise a new textbox will be created by keeping the old one. Now it is detaching the old one and create a new one with same id and tokeninput. Searching also doing successfully. But i am facing one issue.

The token input `$("#token-input-code-" + id[1])` is coming under `<ul><li></li></ul` and this li and ul is not getting removed so a small line will appear in the row top each time i done a change in select list.
How can i remove the ul and li. It does not have an id only a class and the same class is used for another ul element in the form also.

Comment: So you want to remove the ul when empty and the li as well?

Comment: why you want to detach it when creating new one with same id? why don't you just change the content / code as per requirement?

Comment: dear ekuusela, yup i need to remove the ul when empty and the li as well

Comment: Dear Bhushan, Since the table row is dynamic and textbox is attached with jquery token input i am not able to do that. I need to pass extra parameter to the jquery tokeninput. If only the default parameter i don't have to detach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('ul:has(li:empty)').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).children().length === 1; 
}).remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/hdo3o0e4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use  jquery's [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
    var el = $('div[id^="token-input-code"]');
        el.parent('li').unwrap();
        el.parent('ul').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the parent elements with a function like this:

```
function detachInput(id) {
    var li = $('#' + id).closest('li');
    if (li.siblings().length === 0) {
        li.closest('ul').detach();
    } else {
        li.detach();
    }
}
```

This assumes that `ul` elements can contain multiple `li` elements and that you only want to remove the `ul` when it's empty.

Invoke it like this:

```
detachInput("token-input-code-" + id[1]);
```

You should consider whether you really want to [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) or actually [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: what is the diff between detach and remove?

Comment: I linked to the documentation for both of them. The difference is explained almost at the very top of the detach documentation.

Comment: Wonderful..it's working fine..I changed .detached to .remove because i don't want to reuse it. Thanks for the help